# How can I convert this list of pairs into an object that contains an array of arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, list, arraylist, std-pair

I have a list of pairs, and each pair holds two integer values. 
How can I convert this list of pairs into an object that contains an array of edges similar to what is presented in edges[] below? I have created a Graph class, but in order to use it, I need these pairs, which will be my edges, converted into an array of arrays, where each array within the array will hold one pair of two integer values.

This is my list containing the pairs of integer values:

`list<pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > myList;`

This is the struct i created to hold the two edges:

```
struct Edge {
    int source
    int destination;
};
```

This array of edges is an example of what I want my list of pairs to be converted into:

```
Edge edges[] =
        {
            { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 0 }, { 2, 1 }
        };
```

If I need to be more specific about a particular part of the question, let me know and I will be happy to elaborate. Thanks

Comment: `Edge edges[]` -- That is an array of `Edge`'s, not an array of arrays.

Comment: Also, can this be a `std::vector<Edge>`, and not simply an array?  If it is an array, then the size of the array must be fixed, thus the `list::size()` has to be known at compile-time.

Comment: This is the constructor for my graph class: ```Graph(Edge edges[], int n, int N)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP asked in comment to other answer on how possible implementations could look like.

In the original question it was stated:

- OP has a list with data `list<pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > myList;`
- OP wants to use a struct with 2 members for usage in a graph
- OP wants to convert the list into an array

I think OP's idea to have a struct to hold the values is a logical good approach. We have a Graph and the Graph contains several edges. Very reasonable.

So, let us define a class Graph and we will add an array of edges. But since we are in C++, we will not use a plain C-Style array, but a `std::vector`.

If we would use the vector of struct Edge, it could be used in the same way as the list:

```
std::vector<Edge> sameAsList{ { 0U, 1U }, { 1U, 2U }, { 2U, 0U }, { 2U, 1U } };
```

And we can easily convert the original list into such vector, even, if it is encapsulated in a Graph class. There are many possible implementations. I show the maybe most popular 3 versions.

- Using iterators. That would be the pre C++11 solution
- Range base for loop. Available since C++1. Easy to understand and easy to read
- Transormation with `std::transform`. Maybe the "more modern" C++ solution

Please see

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

// Define aliases. To make reading easier
using PairOfUint = std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>;
using ListOfPairs = std::list<PairOfUint>;

// Our struct for edges
struct Edge {
    Edge() {}
    Edge(unsigned int s, unsigned int d) : source(s), destination(d) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Edge& e) { return os << e.source << " " << e.destination; }

    unsigned int source{};
    unsigned int destination{};
};


class Graph
{
public:
    Graph() : edges() {}

    // 3 differnt conversion functions from list of pair to vector of struct. All have the same result
    void add1(ListOfPairs& lop);
    void add2(ListOfPairs& lop);
    void add3(ListOfPairs& lop);

    // Reset edges vector to empty 
    void clearEdges() { edges.clear(); }

    // Inserter. For this example, just print edges
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Graph& g) {
        std::copy(g.edges.begin(), g.edges.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Edge>(os, "\n")); return os;
    }

protected:
    std::vector<Edge> edges{};
};

void Graph::add1(ListOfPairs& lop)
{
    for (ListOfPairs::const_iterator cIterLop = lop.cbegin(); cIterLop != lop.cend(); ++cIterLop)
        edges.emplace_back(Edge(cIterLop->first, cIterLop->second));
}

void Graph::add2(ListOfPairs& lop)
{
    for (const PairOfUint& poui : lop)
        edges.emplace_back(Edge(poui.first, poui.second));
}

void Graph::add3(ListOfPairs& lop)
{
    std::transform(lop.begin(), lop.end(), std::back_inserter(edges), [](const PairOfUint & poui) {
        return Edge(poui.first, poui.second); });
}


ListOfPairs myList{ { 0U, 1U }, { 1U, 2U }, { 2U, 0U }, { 2U, 1U } };

int main()
{
    Graph graph{};

    graph.add1(myList);
    std::cout << "\nVersion1 with iterators:\n" << graph;

    graph.clearEdges();
    graph.add2(myList);
    std::cout << "\n\nVersion2 with range based for:\n" << graph;

    graph.clearEdges();
    graph.add3(myList);
    std::cout << "\n\nVersion3 with std::transform for:\n" << graph;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use vectors instead? They are just dynamic arrays.

you could do something like this.

```
class Edge 
{
public:
    //your 2d array. you can access values by doing edges[x][y]
    std::vector< std::vector<unsigned int> > edges;

    //To initialize you could create a constructor like this
    Edge(list<pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > myList)
    {
        while(myList.size() > 0)
        {
            vector<unsigned int> temp;
            temp.push_back(myList.front().first);
            temp.push_back(myList.front().second);
            edges.push_back(temp);
            myList.pop_front();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not doing any encapsulation, just sharing an idea for creating an object.

Comment: For temp.push_back(myList[i].first);  and temp.push_back(myList[i].second);  it says: Type 'list<pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >' does not provide a subscript operator

Comment: This is a really bad solution. Use a vector of Edge inside the class. Then do not copy the list and pop the elements from it later. Handover as refrence. Then use a range based for, or, best, ````std::transform````

Comment: How would I do that? @ArminMontigny

Answer (score 0):

PaulMcKenzie's comment seems to be the best solution, instead of maintaining two containers ( std::list and array/vector) , you can use only `std::vector<Edge>`.

```
std::vector <Edge> vec{ { 0, 1 },{ 1, 2 },{ 2, 0 },{ 2, 1 } };    
int main() {
    std::cout << vec[0].source << " " << vec[0].destination ;
    for (auto e : vec) {
       e.source = e.destination = 0;
    }
}
```